# File upload no longer works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app that has used the same file upload code for about 8 years. It was designed to work in browsers back before form data was available for managing file uploads.  The architecture is MVC and jQuery.  Just recently it stopped working in Chrome. The code uses a hidden form with a file input to post to a the file upload controller.  The form response is directed to a hidden iframe and the load event is used to react to the response.

Code snippet

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('name', "iframe");
iframe.setAttribute('id', "iframe");
//$("#iframe_" + id).load(function () { iframeLoad() });
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'javascript:false');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
$("#iframe_" + id).load(function () { iframeLoad() });  
// create the form
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('id', "fileUploadForm");
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
form.setAttribute('action', 'the file upload controller path');
// output the response to the iframe
form.setAttribute('target', "iframe");
form.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.appendChild(input);
form.submit();
... and do clean up

... and a function to listen for the reponse from the controller
function iframeLoad() { ...  }
```

If the event listener is created AFTER appending the iframe to the DOM then this works in IE Edge Firefox, but in Chrome the form is never submitted and the load event fires with no response.

If the event listener is created AFTER appending the iframe to the DOM then Chrome will submit the form but the load event never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this with another developer and we concluded that this legacy file upload method is just not going to work any more in Chrome. So I added code to check for that and use a different method for modern browsers.

```
if (typeof input.files !== "undefined") {
    if (input.files.length > 0) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', input.files[0], name);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'path to controller',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            timeout: 45000,
            success: function (response) {
            ... etc.
```